# Splice elements on splice array

Tags: arrays

I have very specyfic problem with task "Sum without highest and lowest number" in codewars. I know how do it and I pass this but improve myself is my way.

Topic: Sum all the numbers of the array except the highest and the lowest element.

My code:

```
    function sumArray(array) {
if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length <= 1) return 0;
var minMax = [];
minMax.push(Math.min.apply(Math,array));
minMax.push(Math.max.apply(Math,array));
var temp;
while (minMax.length != 0){
  temp = (array.indexOf(minMax.splice(0,1)));
  array.splice( temp, 1);
}
// array.splice(array.indexOf(Math.min.apply(Math,array)), 1);
// array.splice(array.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,array)), 1);
return array;
}
```

Example tests: `sumArray([ 6, 2, 1, 8, 10 ])`

Can I pass task this way?

My output `[6, 2, 1]`

Comment: What happens when you have more than one elements that are highest or lowest e.g [1,1,3,4,5,8,8,8]. Do we subtract all of the highest and lowest elements or just pick one

Comment: Thanks for open my eyes!  My code now:
`function sumArray(array) {
// block if !array and array length <= 2
if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length <= 2) return 0;
return array.sort(function(a,b){
  return a - b;
}).slice(1,array.length - 1).reduce(function(a,b){
  return a+b;
});
}`